# Generate Calendar Table Representing a Full Calendar Month

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, date, calendar

I'm attempting to create a calendar table representing a full month in a calendar including overlap days from previous and next months.

I've gotten pretty close with the following script which I have adapted from another site/post:

```
DECLARE
      @year     INT = 2019
    , @month    INT = 1
;

DECLARE
      @firstDOM DATETIME
    , @lastDOM  DATETIME
    , @firstDay VARCHAR(10)
    , @weekid   TINYINT
    , @opDate   DATE

    , @firstDOW DATE
    , @lastDOW  DATE
;

-- get mid-month operation date
SELECT @opDate = CONVERT(DATE, (CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(@month AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-15'))
;

-- get first day of month
SET @firstDOM = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @opDate), 0)
;

-- get last day of month
SET @lastDOM = DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @opDate) + 1, 0))
;

-- get first day of week
SET @firstDOW = @firstDOM - DATEPART(dw, @firstDOM) + 1
;

-- get last day of week
SET @lastDOW = @lastDOM + (7 - DATEPART(dw, @lastDOM))
;

-- get first day name
SELECT @firstDay = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @firstDOW)
;

---------- Recursive CTE to get Days and Dates for the month
;WITH cte_cal ([Date], [Day], [WeekID])
as (
    SELECT
          @firstDOW
        , @firstDay
        , DATEPART(WW, @firstDOW) AS WeekID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
          DATEADD(DD, 1, [Date])
        , CAST(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DD, 1, [Date])) AS VARCHAR(10))
        , DATEPART(WW, DATEADD(DD, 1, [Date]))AS WeekID
    FROM
        cte_cal
    WHERE
        [Date] < @lastDOW
)
------- Use Pivot to display the result in calender format
SELECT
    [WeekID], [Sunday] , [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday]
FROM (
    SELECT
        [WeekID], [Date], [DAY]
    FROM
        cte_cal
) pvt
PIVOT (
    MAX([Date]) FOR [Day] IN ([Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday])
) Pvttab
;
```

However, January and December aren't behaving correctly as can be seen in the following image where each month is triggered for 2019:

[Calendar table output with incorrect January and December values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBSMq.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How could a month have an overlap day? `1 December` is a first december. There are no overlaps in Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @Ярослав Машко Have a look at the attached image. When I say overlap, imagine looking at a physical calendar. For December 2019 you'll see the dates for Jan 1, 2020 through Jan 4, 2020 shown on the December calendar page.

Comment: Still the dates do not overlap. And my calendar shows Jan 1 through 5 on the page. Do you awere of the fact that many coutries have different start of the week day?

Comment: Maybe "overlap" isn't the best choice of words, but I need results as shown in the attached image. E.g., A query for December also fills in Jan 1, 2020 through Jan 4, 2020 in the last line of the table.

For my purposes, I don't need to worry about the rest of the world. :)

Comment: Great. Have to admit that this site do not approve usage of images as a description. At least your image was a table data. With the SQL topic. So me just skipped the image, do not really getting insights in your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I noticed the current T-Sql, I started to wonder if it really needed that many variables.

So I kinda started to scribble from scratch.

The result works for `DATEFIRST 7` (Sunday start).

The recursive CTE only unfolds the dates for the month.
But it's seeded with a correction for the first date of the week, even if that week starts in the previous year.  Similar for the end date.

Because most date related info can be derived from a date.

```
DECLARE @year INT, @month INT;
SET @year = YEAR(GetDate());
SET @month = 1;
SET DATEFIRST 7;

WITH CTE_DATES AS
(
    SELECT 
     DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1)), DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1)) AS [Date],
     DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1) AS initDate,
     DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1))   )), EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1)))  AS endDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(day,1, [Date]), initDate, endDate
    FROM CTE_DATES
    WHERE [Date] < endDate
), 
CTE_CALENDAR AS
(
  SELECT 
   (CASE
    WHEN MONTH(initDate) = 1 AND DATEPART(WW, [Date]) > 50
    THEN 1
    WHEN YEAR([Date]) > YEAR(initDate)
    THEN DATEPART(WW, EOMONTH(initDate))
    ELSE DATEPART(WW, [Date])
    END) AS [WeekID], 
   DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [Date]) AS [Day],
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Date],23) AS [Date]
  FROM CTE_DATES
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_CALENDAR
PIVOT 
(
   MAX([Date]) 
   FOR [Day] IN ([Sunday] , [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday])
) Pvt
ORDER BY [WeekID];
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/PODG65672)

Comment: I chose this as the accepted answer as it works straight up with no changes, keeps the WeekID as a reference and is a bit easier for me to wrap me head around. Many, many, many thanks to LukStorms, BJones and John Cappelletti. It's awesome people like you that make this community so awesome and valuable!

Comment: @webface Thx :)  Btw, this reminded me that I had to double check something. The correction on the workweek uses the ww of dec-31.  But wasn't sure if datepart would dare to calculate it as 1.  But gladly it's either 53 or 54.  `WITH D(d) AS (SELECT CAST('2000-12-31' AS DATE) UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,1, d) FROM D WHERE d<CAST('2099-12-31' AS DATE))SELECT  DATEPART(WW,d) ww, COUNT(*) cnt FROM D GROUP BY DATEPART(WW,d) ORDER BY ww`

Answer (score 1):

Made some minor changes to your query to catch the problem weeks. May want to do a little QA to make sure it will work in all scenarios. Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3954f/18/0)

Specifically in the CTE (both unioned queries) I added a `CASE` statement to force the week to a 1 or a 53:

```
...
, CASE WHEN YEAR(@firstDOW) = @year + 1 THEN 52
       WHEN YEAR(@firstDOW) = @year - 1 THEN 1
  ELSE DATEPART(WW, @firstDOW) END AS WeekID

  UNION ALL

...
, CASE WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(DD, 1, [Date])) = @year + 1 THEN 53
       WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(DD, 1, [Date])) = @year - 1 THEN 1
  ELSE DATEPART(WW, DATEADD(DD, 1, [Date])) END AS WeekID
...
```

All together:

```
DECLARE
  @year     INT = 2020
, @month    INT = 12
, @firstDOM DATETIME
, @lastDOM  DATETIME
, @firstDay VARCHAR(10)
, @weekid   TINYINT
, @opDate   DATE
, @firstDOW DATE
, @lastDOW  DATE


-- get mid-month operation date
SELECT @opDate = CONVERT(DATE, (CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(@month AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-15'))


-- get first day of month
SET @firstDOM = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @opDate), 0)


-- get last day of month
SET @lastDOM = DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @opDate) + 1, 0))


-- get first day of week
SET @firstDOW = @firstDOM - DATEPART(dw, @firstDOM) + 1


-- get last day of week
SET @lastDOW = @lastDOM + (7 - DATEPART(dw, @lastDOM))


-- get first day name
SELECT @firstDay = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @firstDOW)


---------- Recursive CTE to get Days and Dates for the month
;WITH cte_cal ([Date], [Day], [WeekID])
as (
    SELECT
          @firstDOW
        , @firstDay
        , CASE WHEN YEAR(@firstDOW) = @year + 1 THEN 52
               WHEN YEAR(@firstDOW) = @year - 1 THEN 1
          ELSE DATEPART(WW, @firstDOW) END AS WeekID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
          DATEADD(DD, 1, [Date])
        , CAST(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DD, 1, [Date])) AS VARCHAR(10))
        , CASE WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(DD, 1, [Date])) = @year + 1 THEN 53
               WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(DD, 1, [Date])) = @year - 1 THEN 1
          ELSE DATEPART(WW, DATEADD(DD, 1, [Date])) END AS WeekID
    FROM
        cte_cal
    WHERE
        [Date] < @lastDOW
)
------- Use Pivot to display the result in calender format
SELECT
    [WeekID], [Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], 
[Saturday]
FROM (
    SELECT
        [WeekID], [Date], [DAY]
    FROM
        cte_cal
) pvt
PIVOT (
    MAX([Date]) FOR [Day] IN ([Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday])
) Pvttab
;
```

Comment: Hi @BJones, Many thanks for the adjustment. So far looking good!  I'll run some tests on it and will be sure to follow up or mark as the accepted answer soon! Thank you!

Comment: +1 for limited changes to the original script, however I noticed an issue with the last week of 2017 and the first week of 2018 where 2017-12-31 in 2018 was marked as WeekID 53. I resolved this by removing DATEADD from the CTE invocation. Also, I think the clause "WHEN YEAR((at)firstDOW) = (at)year + 1 THEN 52" in the invocation is also not needed as (at)firstDOW is derived from (at)firstDOM, so the year for (at)firstDOW is always going to be the year of the month we're querying for or the previous year, not the next year.

Comment: Minor modification to fix the 2017 and 2018 problem for anyone else scrolling on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option

**Example**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2020-02-01'

Select RowNr,[Sun],[Mon],[Tue],[Wed],[Thu],[Fri],[Sat]
 From  (
        Select D
              ,DOW=left(datename(WEEKDAY,d),3)
              ,RowNr = sum(Flg) over (order by D)
         From (
                Select D,Flg=case when datename(WEEKDAY,d)= 'Sunday' then 1 else 0 end
                 From (Select Top (42) D=DateAdd(DAY,-7+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) From  master..spt_values n1 ) A
              ) A
       ) src
 Pivot (max(d) for DOW in ([Sun],[Mon],[Tue],[Wed],[Thu],[Fri],[Sat]) )pvg
 Where [Sun] is not null
   and [Sat] is not null
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Upvoted as this works great and is impressively concise albeit somewhat over my head!